# Merge Alternating Rows

Tags: r, dataframe, rows

I extracted data from a pdf and have a small issue. Some **cells got seperated in two rows**, for the data to have NA in some cells, and values in others. These values I want to simply **merge into the above cell**.

Interestingly, every "real" line to which I want to merge the other ones starts with the same symbol, namely a "§".

I have about ~1000 observations so automated solution would be amazing

```
first <- c("§", "3", "4")
second <- c(NA, "2", NA)
third <- c("§", "2", 5)
fourth <- c(NA, "2", "3")
... and so on

df <- as.data.frame(rbind(first, second, third, fourth))

expected output: 
first_e <- c("§", "32", "4")
second_e <- c "§", "22", "53")

df_e <- as.data.frame(rbind(first_e, second_e))
```

It would be truly amazing if someone had an idea (:

best from berlin

Comment: Can you share your expected output.

Comment: If I understand you correctly there is not allways a second line - Therefore it will be difficult to separate what defines a "second" and what a "frist" line. Meaning you would have to be sure, that "second" lines allways have at least one NA and "first" lines never have any NA. That would be the minimum assumption to "automate"

Comment: hi, there is always a second line - however, some are empty, some have values.

Comment: Expected output: 

```
output <- c("4", "32", "4")
```

Comment: Another possiblity is that all the "actual" lines start with the same symbol, namely a "§". I edited the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution if there is allways a second line would be this:

```
library(dplyr)
```

library(dplyr)

```
df %>% 
  # use the row number as colum
  dplyr::mutate(ID = dplyr::row_number()) %>% 
  # substract 1 from very even row numer to build groups
  dplyr::mutate(ID = ifelse(ID %% 2 == 0, ID - 1, ID)) %>% 
  # group by the new ID
  dplyr::group_by(ID) %>% 
  # convert all NAs to "" (empty string)
  dplyr::mutate_all(~ ifelse(is.na(.), "", .)) %>% 
  # concatenate all strings per group
  dplyr::mutate_all( ~ paste(., collapse = "")) %>% 
  # select only distinct cases (do elimitate "seconds" as the now are identical to "frists)
  dplyr::distinct()


  V1    V2    V3       ID
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1 4     32    4         1
```

I left the created ID number in the result but you can drop/delete it after the calculations if you prefer

Comment: I suppose the POSIXct came only in the first line so the second for them is NA: If so you could cast/mutate the POSIXct column to character before the operation and cast/mutate it back after wards - since you will be adding "noting" this should solve the issue

Comment: hey it worked out perfectly fine, thank you so much ! ((::

Comment: hey ja, didnt delete the prior comment on purpose - conversion to char works

Comment: @lupo404 please accept my answer as correct so other know this has been solved! https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

Simply paste the odd elements of a column with even elements:

```
# vectors of TRUEs in odd or even positions
odd <- rep(c(T,F), length.out=nrow(df))
evn <- rep(c(F,T), length.out=nrow(df))

# for each column...
result <- lapply(df, function(col) {
    paste0(ifelse(is.na(col[odd]), '', col[odd]),
           ifelse(is.na(col[evn]), '', col[evn]))  
})
as.data.frame(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider flagging `§` columns with a `ifelse` + `cumsum` to generate a grouping field for `aggregate` with `paste`:

```r
# BUILD DATA FRAME
df <- setNames(rbind.data.frame(first, second, third, fourth, stringsAsFactors=FALSE),
               c("col1", "col2", "col3"))

# CONVERT ALL NAs TO EMPTY STRING
df[is.na(df)] <- ""

# GENERATE GROUPING COLUMN
df$section <- cumsum(ifelse(df$col1 == "§", 1, 0))
df
#   col1 col2 col3 section
# 1    §    3    4       1
# 2         2            1
# 3    §    2    5       2
# 4         2    3       2

# AGGREGATE BY GROUPING COLUMNS
clean_df <- aggregate(. ~ section, df, paste, collapse="")[-1]
clean_df
#   col1 col2 col3
# 1    §   32    4
# 2    §   22   53
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/ZVT44512)</kbd>

Comment: that looks like a really interesting approach, will check it out monday! thanks a ton!